# How to get the value of a textbox or dropdownlist from another page?

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I need to get the value of a textbox or a dropdownlist from another page in order to edit a particular record.

I have a gridview list of a business group details in EditEmployee page

[image: EditDetailsPage]

and if I click update link button it will successfully be updated including the record in HeadCountUpdating page but I only need to edit a record in a particular year and period in headcountupdating page

[image: HeadCountUpdatingPage]

How can I get the value of a textbox from another page in order to put it on my query?

```
        Dim JobTitle As String = DirectCast(gvGroup.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txtgvJobTitle"), TextBox).Text
        Dim BusinessUnit As String = DirectCast(gvGroup.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("ddl_gvBusinessUnit"), DropDownList).Text
        Dim Division As String = DirectCast(gvGroup.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("ddl_gvDivision"), DropDownList).Text
        Dim SubDivision As String = DirectCast(gvGroup.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("ddl_gvSubDivision"), DropDownList).Text
        Dim Classification As String = DirectCast(gvGroup.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("ddl_gvClassification"), DropDownList).Text
        Dim SubClassification As String = DirectCast(gvGroup.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("ddl_gvSubClassification"), DropDownList).Text
        Dim MASTERID As String = DirectCast(gvGroup.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("lblMasterID"), Label).Text
        Dim empno As String = lblval_Empno.Text
        Dim updatePeriodTblResult As Boolean

updatePeriodTblResult = UpdateInsDelRecord("UPDATE PERIOD_TBL SET BUSINESS_UNIT = '" & BusinessUnit & "', DIVISION = '" & Division & "'," & _
                                                           "SUB_DIVISION = '" & SubDivision & "', CLASSIFICATION = '" & Classification & "'," & _
                                                           "SUB_CLASSIFICATION = '" & SubClassification & "', JOBTITLE = '" & JobTitle & "' " & _
                                                           "WHERE MASTERID = '" & MASTERID & "' AND EMPNO = '" & empno & "'")
```

Comment: have you tried `Dim value As String = OtherForm.TextBox1.Text`?

Comment: like Dim c_year As String = theaspxpage.textbox1.text? @kiLLua

Comment: `TextBox1` is the name of the textbox from other page. try it first. then come back if it stil doesn't work

Comment: yeah i already tried this Dim c_year As String = TM1Updating.aspx.txt_year.text but Name 'TM1Updating' is not declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In the source page, save the information that you want to pass in session state
  `Session("field1") = "value1"`
- In the target page, read the saved information from session state
  `Dim field1 as String = CType(Session.Item("field1"), String)`

Read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx) for more.